# How to integrate sass and bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I install laravel and I dont understand how to use sass and bootstrap.

We get in the resources folder "/reosources/sass/app.scss" this content:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600");

@import "variables";

@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheet/bootstrap"
```

The public/css/app.css has the bootstrap styles.

In the welcome view I can use bootstrap classes. But now how to use sass with bootstrap?  For example if I want to define some variables like:

```
$background-white #fff;
$background-red: red;
```

And apply this variables to the bootstrap html, I should define this variables in the _variable.scss? And then to use the variables I need to change in app.css? Im trying to do this but the colors are not applied. In the app.css I put, for example, in the bootstrap body this:

```
  body{
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",
Helvetica,Arial,
sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
line-height:1.42857143;
color:#333;
background-color:#fff}
```

If I change to:

```
body{
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",
Helvetica,Arial,
sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
line-height:1.42857143;
color:#333;
background-color:$background-red}
```

It is not working, the background dont change to red. Can you give a help to understand how this works? Thanks!

Comment: You need to run "npm install" in the root of your laravel installation, then call gulp to update js and css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read Laravel mix [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix)

You need to start by installing npm packages. run `npm install` in the command line. Edit the _variable.scss file. Then run `npm run dev` to build the new `public/css/app.css` which will have the changes.

In your blade file, you link to the app.css using `mix()` helper.

```
`<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`
```

make sure you npm installed. if you're on a mac and use Homebrew run `brew install npm`